# I have problem while running asp.net core mvc project in iis express

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Updated some concepts in my old project. Now the updated project is working properly. But my older project shows the error  "This localhost page can’t be found HTTP ERROR 404". I have tried to clear Visual studio cache by using MEF component. but it's not work.  How to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by Updated project and older project? Do you create a new copy from older project and modify it to Updated project? Do you publish older project or launch the older project from VS and it shows this error?

Answer (score 2):

On a single machine, each **port** can only be served by one process at a time.
If you want to do this simultaneously, you need to use different ports.

So e.g. `https://site/` and `https://site:444/` should work: one process can use the default port = **443** and the other **444**.

Or if you use `http` instead of `https`, then the default port will be `80`.